# Particular Allocating device memory for _global_ function in cuda

Tags: cuda, pycuda

want to do this programm on cuda.

1.in "main.cpp"

```
struct Center{
double * Data;
int dimension;
};
typedef struct Center Center;

//I allow a pointer on N Center elements by the CUDAMALLOC like follow

....
#include "kernel.cu"
....
center *V_dev;
int M =100, n=4; 

cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&V_dev,M*sizeof(Center));
Init<<<1,M>>>(V_dev, M, N); //I always know the dimension of N before calling
```

My "kernel.cu" file is something like this

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include"device_launch_parameters.h"
... //other include headers to allow my .cu file to know the Center type definition

__global__ void Init(Center *V, int N, int dimension){
V[threadIdx.x].dimension = dimension;
V[threadIdx.x].Data = (double*)malloc(dimension*sizeof(double));
for(int i=0; i<dimension; i++)
    V[threadIdx.x].Data[i] = 0; //For the value, it can be any kind of operation returning a float that i want to be able put here

}
```

I'm on visual studio 2008 and CUDA 5.0. When I Build my project, I've got these errors:

```
error: calling a _host_ function("malloc") from a _global_ function("Init") is not allowed.
```

I want to know please how can I perform this? (I know that 'malloc' and other cpu memory allocation are not allowed for device memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`malloc` *is* [allowed in device code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#dynamic-global-memory-allocation-and-operations) but you have to be compiling for a cc2.0 or greater target GPU.

Adjust your VS project settings to remove any GPU device settings like `compute_10,sm_10` and replace it with `compute_20,sm_20` or higher to match your GPU. (And, to run that code, your GPU needs to be cc2.0 or higher.)

Comment: My GPU Device is "Geforce 210", with a cuda capability major/Minor version number of 1.2 Does this means that it allows my device to change project settings compute_10,sm_10 to perform my operations? When I list the CUDA runtime API /GPU of my project, I have the following:    GPU Architecture(1): sm_10    GPU Architecture(2):sm_20. What does it means?

Comment: Then, no, you can't do `malloc` from device code.  Instead, figure out how much memory you need, and allocate it before the kernel call using `cudaMalloc`, and pass a pointer to it to your kernel.  You can easily create an array of `double` this way, and then assign each `V[threadIdx.x].Data` to be pointing to various locations in this array, in your kernel code.

Comment: That is the way I've tried, but How can I allow enough space needed for each of my Center.Data?can I do this? `code` cudaMalloc((void**)&V_dev,M*sizeof(Center)*n);

Comment: @dadson `sizeof(Center)` equals `sizeof(double*) + sizeof(int)`, I don't think thats what you want. If you know the dimension, i.e. `N` even at compile time, then you could replace `double * Data;` with statically sized array `double Data[N];`. Then the code you posted should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need the compiler parameter `-arch=sm_20` and a GPU which supports it.